# HTTParty and text/xml

Tags: ruby, xml, api, content-type, httparty

I'm trying to make a POST request using HTTParty, in which I need the content-type to be text/xml. How can I make that happen? Right now the API I'm calling is complaining I'm not sending any xml. If I call it using curl I get the same error, unless I specify content-type to text/xml.

Comment: hmmm... apparently just by setting :body to the xml content already does the trick. However, the server still doesn't seem to be receiving the xml content... I'm at a loss now...

Comment: Does the content type really need to be `text/xml` or do you only need a content type that states that the document is XML? In the latter case text/xml is usually not recommended (in favor of e.g. `application/xml`). Sending as `text/xml` always needs also a charset header or you need to encode your XML as ASCII. This is also W3C's take on this issue. http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#no-text-xml

Comment: Hmm... good question... I need to look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HTTParty.post url, :body => xml, :headers => {'Content-type' => 'text/xml'}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's what I was trying to do... I was just making a noob mistake someplace else. :)